# Order minimum quantities

Tags: 8, commerce

I need to set order minimum quantities in my Commerce 2 website. The website has two stores: retail and wholesale. Customers who are shopping in my "retail consumers" store must have at least 6 products in their cart in order to check out. Customers in my "wholesale consumers" store must have at least 4 products in their cart in order to check out.

My plan is to add a custom Condition that can be used for the two payment gateways that will be used in the stores (one for each store). That custom Condition would allow me to designate a "greater than or equal to" product quantity for each gateway.

This presentation (http://presentations.robiningelbrecht.be/drupalcon-amsterdam-2019/#/6/3) appears to show an example that would do what I need. I followed the steps, but I am unable to see any effect on my website.

Below is the Condition plugin code I have so far:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\order_item_quantity\Plugin\Commerce\Condition;

use Drupal\commerce\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\ConditionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Provides the quantity condition for order items.
 *
 * @CommerceCondition(
 *   id = "order_item_quantity",
 *   label = @Translation("Quantity"),
 *   display_label = @Translation("Limit by quantity"),
 *   category = @Translation("Products"),
 *   entity_type = "commerce_order_item",
 * )
 */
class OrderTotalQuantity extends ConditionBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function evaluate(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $this->assertEntity($entity);

    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItemInterface $order_item */
    $order_item = $entity;
    $quantity = $order_item->getQuantity();

    switch ($this->configuration['operator']) {
      case '==':
        return $quantity == $this->configuration['quantity'];

      case '>=':
        return $quantity >= $this->configuration['quantity'];

      case '>':
        return $quantity > $this->configuration['quantity'];

      case '<=':
        return $quantity <= $this->configuration['quantity'];

      case '<':
        return $quantity < $this->configuration['quantity'];

    }
  }
     

}
```

As you can see, I added additional "case" lines at the bottom of the code. Not sure if that was done correctly. The code does not work with or without those lines.

This is the folder structure where that Condition file resides: /modules/custom/order_item_quantity/src/Plugin/Commerce/Condition/OrderTotalQuantity.php

Additionally, there is an order_item_quantity.info.yml in the /modules/custom/order_item_quantity directory, which contains the following:

```
name: Commerce Product Quantity in Cart
type: module
description: Adds the condition to designate a minimum quantity of products in the cart for payment methods and promotions.
package: Commerce
core: 8.x
```

Lastly, I am also hoping to include a specific error message for each payment gateway ("You must have at least X products in your cart in order to check out"). Not sure if that would be done in this condition file, or elsewhere.

Thanks for any feedback/assistance with this!

=================SOLUTION BELOW=================

Thanks to @sonfd for the assist on this. Here is my solution (I used the code in OrderTotalPrice and also in OrderItemQuantity.php (from the Commerce > Promotions submodule) as a starting point.):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\order_total_quantity\Plugin\Commerce\Condition;

use Drupal\commerce\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\ConditionBase;
use Drupal\commerce_price\Calculator;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
* Provides the quantity condition for order items.
*
* @CommerceCondition(
* id = "order_total_quantity",
* label = @Translation("Quantity"),
* display_label = @Translation("Limit by quantity"),
* category = @Translation("Products"),
* entity_type = "commerce_order",
* weight = 10,
* )
*/
class OrderTotalQuantity extends ConditionBase {

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function defaultConfiguration() {
return [
'operator' => '>',
'quantity' => NULL,
] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

$quantity = $this->configuration['quantity'];

if (isset($quantity) && !isset($quantity['number'])) {
$quantity = NULL;
}

$form['operator'] = [
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Operator'),
'#options' => $this->getComparisonOperators(),
'#default_value' => $this->configuration['operator'],
'#required' => TRUE,
];
$form['quantity'] = [
'#type' => 'number',
'#title' => t('Quantity'),
'#default_value' => $this->configuration['quantity'],
'#min' => 1,
'#required' => TRUE,
];

return $form;
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

$values = $form_state->getValue($form['#parents']);
$this->configuration['operator'] = $values['operator'];
$this->configuration['quantity'] = $values['quantity'];
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function evaluate(EntityInterface $entity) {
$this->assertEntity($entity);
/** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order */
$order = $entity;
$quantity = '0';
foreach ($order->getItems() as $order_item) {
$quantity = Calculator::add($quantity, $order_item->getQuantity());
}

switch ($this->configuration['operator']) {
case '>=':
return $quantity >= $this->configuration['quantity'];

case '>':
return $quantity > $this->configuration['quantity'];

case '<=':
return $quantity <= $this->configuration['quantity'];

case '<':
return $quantity < $this->configuration['quantity'];

case '==':
return $quantity == $this->configuration['quantity'];

default:
throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid operator {$this->configuration['operator']}");
}
}

}
```

Comment: Have you enabled/configured your condition in the gateway?

Comment: The condition never appears in the gateway or in any promotions. When I create a new condition using the example code from https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/core/conditions#conditioninterface-and-conditionbase, that other condition shows up as expected.

Comment: If your plugin isn't showing in the UI, that's usually because your annotation is off. I think you are better off using the `Drupal\commerce_order\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\OrderTotalPrice` as a starting point. It seems much closer to what you're trying to do. Try adapting that code and then update your question here.

Comment: The entity_type = "commerce_order_item" portion of the annotation does appear to be the issue. I changed that to entity_type = "commerce_order", and the plugin is now displayed in the UI. When I select it though, the quantity and greater than (etc) options do not appear.

Comment: I am seeing the following error in the recent logs:

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: Plugin (order_total_quantity) instance class "Drupal\order_item_quantity\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\OrderTotalQuantity" does not exist. in Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory::getPluginClass() (line 97 of /home1/mysite/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Factory/DefaultFactory.php).

Comment: There's no configuration form because you haven't defined it. Look at the `Drupal\commerce_order\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\OrderTotalPrice` I mentioned before. It's doing almost exactly what you want. The only difference is it's adding up the price of all items in the cart instead of just the total number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111402/discussion-between-sonfd-and-hockey2112).